# elfinder upload issue

Tags: php, upload, ckeditor

I have searched on internet but I didn't found any solution. I want to use elfinder globally. I mean, elfinder hosted on somewhere in my web server and I want reach this plugin anywhere.

I send the path and url configs with variable. Every things is ok at the moment.
The problem is; when I upload a file, the error raise; `unable to connect backend`.

I'm using elfinder 2.0. Here is the connector.php configs.

`$path = $_GET['path'];`

`$url = $_GET['dizin'];`

`$opts = array(`

`// 'debug' => true,`

```
`'roots' => array(,`
    array(
        'driver'=> 'LocalFileSystem',
        'path'=> $path, 
        'URL'=> $url,
        'accessControl' => 'access'
    )
)
```

`);`

`path` and `dizin` send with GET method.

I send the `path` like : `home/user/username/www`

Comment: you should not use singleton

Comment: @NullPointer   what does it mean ? So, what can I do?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern